# ArcGIS online reordering popups

Tags: arcgis-online

I’m using the new map viewer and I have two overlapping polygon layers. When I have popups turned on for both layers, but I’d prefer popups for one layer shows up first.

Is there a way to reorder popups without reordering layers?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to make these pop up reordered. I hope esri fixes this soon- it is obnoxious!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).